# Dataflow how to combine PCollections replacing objects

Tags: merge, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I want to implement a process where I load 2 Kinds of data, lets say Kind A and B, `PCollection<A> a1, PCollection<B> b1`. Then I create a View.asMap() from `a1` and give it to a DoFn `dfn1` as sideinput that is applied on `b1`. This DoFn uses some of the values of Kind A and outputs them. Afterwards, I want to create a new `PCollection<A> a2` that holds all the objects of `a1`, but replaces the ones that were outputted by `dfn1`.

Lets say `a1` holds Objects `o1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1`
`dfn1` manipulates and outputs `b1 -> b2, c1 -> c2, g1 -> g2` to `PCollection<A> a2`

the new PCollection combined from `a1` and `a2` should contain `o1, b2, c2, e1, f1, g2`

Is there a built-in mechanism to accomplish something like that? The collections may be keyed before the "merge".

Thanks in advance.

As i am unsatisfied by my english explanation of the problem, here is a DoFn which performs what I was asking for. The real question is, if there is a built-in transform that can do something like this, best would be without manually creating a view before.

```
public class CombineKvCollectionsWithMasterCollection extends DoFn<KV<String, Object>, Object>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4100849850259729106L;

    private PCollectionView<Map<String, Object>> masterView;

    public CombineKvCollectionsWithMasterCollection(PCollectionView<Map<String, Object>> masterView) {
        this.masterView = masterView;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        KV<String, Object> kv = c.element();
        Map<String, Object> masterMap = c.sideInput(masterView);
        if (masterMap.containsKey(kv.getKey())) {
            c.output(masterMap.get(kv.getKey()));
        } else {
            c.output(kv.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [Combine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/combine#advanced-combinations-using-combinefn) function does the basic functions like Sum, Min, Max and Mean. For a [specific combine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/combine#creating-and-specifying-a-combine-function) functionality, you would need to provide some processing logic. So, there is no in-built function that would do this for now.